# For $\psi(x, y, z, t) = Ae^{i[k(\alpha x + \beta y + \gamma z) \mp \omega t]}$, $\alpha^2 + \beta^2 + \gamma^2 = 1$

Tags: waves

I am currently studying *Optics*, fifth edition, by Hecht. I am presented with the plane wave in Cartesian coordinates as follows:

$$\psi(x, y, z, t) = Ae^{i[k(\alpha x + \beta y + \gamma z) \mp \omega t]}$$

I am then told that $\alpha^2 + \beta^2 + \gamma^2 = 1$. Can someone please explain why $\alpha^2 + \beta^2 + \gamma^2 = 1$?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ are the Cartesian components of the unit wavenumber vector. The wavenumber vector is $\mathbf k=(k_x,k_y,k_z)=k(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$. The squares of the components of any unit vector sum to $1$.